# What is the CD-R track space overhead?

Tags: cd-burning, cd-r

I have daily small backup with CD-R with ISO 9660 format, every days there is a new track/session. I know that I can add up to 99 tracks in a single disc, but how can I calculate wasted space by track open, indexes and so on?